# Realloc consistently fails (in C)

Tags: c, realloc

Realloc consistently fails after I add 25 characters.

The error:

Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-minimal.c: 116: realloc: Assertion `ptr == alloc_last_block' failed!

```
char** linePtr = getLinePtr(block, y);
char* tmpPtr = realloc(*linePtr, (strlen(*linePtr) + 1) * sizeof(char));
if (tmpPtr != NULL) {
    *linePtr = tmpPtr;
    strinsert(tmpPtr, ch, x);
}
```

I check the variables right before and everything seems fine. `*linePtr` points to a string of 24 characters and `strlen(*linePtr)` returns 24. The address returned by `realloc` is always the same.

There is no number hard-coded so I have no idea why it always fail after the same number of characters.

`*linePtr` was 1 just one byte at the beginning and I am reallocating one extra byte every time for now.

Edit:

```
char** getLinePtr(Block* block, int y)
{
    assert(y >= block->start && y <= block->start + block->nb_lines);

    if (y == block->start + block->nb_lines) {
        block->lines = realloc(block->lines, (block->nb_lines + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        *(block->lines + block->nb_lines) = malloc(sizeof(char));
        block->nb_lines++;
    }
    return block->lines + block->nb_lines - 1;
}
```

Edit2:

By pasting the code I realise there is a bug in getLinePtr: It returns the last line instead of the one asked (using y), but it should not change anything to this bug. And only the first line is used.

Comment: Side note: you're doing that reallocation as inefficiently as possible.

Comment: What does `getLinePtr()` return? How does it construct the return value?

Comment: If the `realloc` in `block->lines = realloc(block->lines, (block->nb_lines + 1) * sizeof(char*));` fails, you have a nasty memory leak and undefined behaviour when using `block->lines` thereafter (directly or indirectly).

Comment: What does `strinsert(tmpPtr, ch, x);` do? With `char* tmpPtr = realloc(*linePtr, (strlen(*linePtr) + 1) * sizeof(char));`, unless you have previously written outside the allocated area, you're not growing the allocated memory, but either keep it constant or shrink it, since a string needs `strlen(s)+1` bytes (one for the 0-terminator).

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that the problem is that the pointer that is being passed to `realloc` is not a pointer that was returned by `realloc` or `malloc`.  There are several pieces missing from the shown code to be able to know that for sure. But you should verify that `getLinePtr` is returning a "pointer to the allocated pointer" (I'm not saying that is a good way to do it, but that is how it is being used in the shown code).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to reallocate (strlen(*linePtr) + 2) instead of (strlen(*linePtr) + 1).

strlen returns the size of the string without the terminating null character. So I need to add 1 for it and I need to add 1 for the character to be added right after.

Thanks to Daniel Fisher for the hint.